# Adding reusable interface or enum code snippets in VS Code/Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-code

How can I add *reusable* `interface` or `enum` code snippets in VS Code/Visual Studio like XCode? That is, when I wanna type the same `enum` code again in my file, it just loads instantly(using IntelliSense) from the snippets library and I can press enter key to load all that `enum` code again in my file. How can I do this in VS Code/Visual Studio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done by referring this link https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/customization/userdefinedsnippets